# Actionscript3 play multiple sounds

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I am writing a simple Flash space-shooter-type game. Every time the player fires or an enemy is shot I play a sound. The problem is sound appear to be "blocking" - if the player shoots very often (i.e. before previous sound has finished) the new sound will not play until the previous one has finished. Here is my code:

```
//constructor- pre-load all sounds 
fireSound = new Sound();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("fire.mp3");
fireSound.load(req);    

//enter frame listener- play sound
//if space bar pressed
fireSound.play();
//if enemy shot
otherSound.play();
```

Comment: Are you using the SoundChannel class? It's something you should consider. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html

Comment: The way I understand the documentation, playing a sound will automatically assign a sound to a channel. I can't figure out if they all go to the same channel, which causes my problems, or go to separate channels and play concurrently.

Comment: If you instantiate a `SoundChannel` and then assign a sound to it, you will be able to play sounds over each other as much as you want. For example, `var sc:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel(); sc = sound1.play();`. You'll want to use a `SoundChannel` anyways as it allows for more control over the sound (stopping, pausing, etc).

Comment: you should be aware, that there is limited amount of concurrent SoundChannel